# Grunt shows this errorWarning: OptionParser::InvalidOption: invalid option: --source-map Use --trace for backtrace. Use --force to continue

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I have tried to remove sourceMap in grunt.js file but than it shows the other error about sourceMapEmbed

```
sass: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceMapEmbed: true,
        sourceMapContents: true,
        includePaths: ['bower_components']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
          src: ['*.{scss,sass}'],
          dest: '.tmp/styles',
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      },
      server: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
          src: ['*.{scss,sass}'],
          dest: '.tmp/styles',
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      }
    },
```

Comment: You should include your gruntfile.